# What are the consolations of Atheism?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

Religion is often popularly characterised by atheists as a consolation. One can turn this around and ask what are the consolations of atheism?

To answer this question correctly is to mirror the usual atheistic one. That is the worldview comprehensively takes the religious and without giving perhaps their due straight out says that why they believe is that it is the site for unconscious consolation.

This needs to be turned around and asked how the atheistic one is an unconscious consolation from a religious view (not necessarily from a Christian one).

I'm not positing that there actually *is* an unconscious motivation (though if one believes in Freud much of our behaviour does); it's a hypothesis to examine the suppositions of atheism and understand its contours and limitations.

It surely makes a difference if one is examining a *consolation* from a Christian, Islamic, Buddhist or Hindu viewpoint. Modern Atheism is not the first time a reaction has developed against a state religion: The Lokyata in Vedic India and Epicureanism in Greek antiquity. I'm sure that there will be others.

What I'm performing here is a Derridean deconstructionist move. *Consolations of religion* is a notion that is a traditional charge against religion from at least Epicurus's time.

Comment: I would seriously recommend letting Christopher Hitchens answer this question. I doubt anybody here would cover it more completely and eloquently. ;) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HA55jGyq2C8

Comment: I dunno, maybe something like "my life is really my own and can be lived for my own reasons and not as a means to some religious end (e.g., heaven)"?

Comment: @David H:I've read Christopher Hitchens. I was hoping for something more substantial :).

Comment: You might be interested in [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Philosophers-without-Gods-Meditations-Atheism/dp/019974341X) (again, another shameless plug for one of my professors). I'm not sure how directly it will touch upon this question, but it contains stories of atheistic philosophers and their journeys towards atheism. The second part considers some "problems" of atheism and might address this somewhere in there. I must confess that I have only read a bit of the book, though.

Comment: Removed the [philosophy-of-science] tag. I'm kind of on an "appropriate tagging" kick lately. I think that our tags need to be a bit more tightly monitored (the [logic] being the one most often misappropriated).

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks, I'll look it up. I'm beginning to think that philosophy is theology for atheists:). I've elaborated my question a little to say what I mean by *consolation*.

Comment: It's not clear why you find Hitchins insubstantial, though I would grant that the linked video can only answer your question by omission of the features of religion (and especially Christianity) upon which he touches.

Comment: A preoccupation with the next world clearly shows an inability to cope credibly with this one. If you're religious and you believe in another life somehow, that means you don't live this life to the full because you think you're going to get another life.  Religion is the wish to feel that you have a kind of elder brother who will stand by you in all your troubles and disputes. Religions are a dangerous doctrine, because the more likely we are to assume that the solution comes from the outside, the less likely we are to solve our problems ourselves.

Comment: Well, the comments are beginning to show what I thought might be an issue (and what I fear I've contributed to). I'm afraid that this question might be "not constructive" absent some further context. For instance, you might find some serious argument that levels the charge of "belief (only?) for the sake of consolation" against religious followers and ask whether a similar argument could be lodged against a non-religious person. As it stands, though, I'm now pretty solidly of the opinion that this question defies a clear answer and is likely to only prompt discussion.

Comment: @Dennis Maybe this question would be more at home over at cogsci.SE?

Comment: @Dennis: Ok, I'll add some more context.

Comment: @DavidH Can't say for sure since I don't know enough about cognitive science, but I'd guess not. The problem is lack of specification, not inappropriate topic. For instance, this might be reframed as a question about epistemic norms and what is a good or bad reason to believe. That would be a question that would need to be addressed before even getting to the presupposition (or what seems to be a presupposition) that "belief only for the sake of consolation" is a bad thing.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to give some motivation for why you suspect that atheism has corresponding subconscious consolations, as those attributed to religion by atheists. What has led you to this question?

Comment: @deBeaudrap: He's answering the question from the viewpoint of an athiest. In the comparison I'm invoking this would be like asking a muslim why he believes. I'm specifically asking for a critique of atheism theologically exposited from a believer.

Comment: @deBeaudrap: Modern Western atheism isn't the first time a reaction has developed against a state religion. Lokyata in Vedic civilisation, and Epicurianism in Greek antiquity. I'm sure that there are others. I don't believe that there is an unconscious motivation (but if you believe Freud then much does) - it's a hypothesis to examine the suppositions of atheism.

Comment: I believe the classic religious answer is that atheists are free to act independently of traditional morality, to disregard scripture, and to hubristically hold themselves to be on a par with god by way of presuming to be able to comprehend and manipulate nature. Is that the sort of thing you're looking for, or are you perhaps hunting for something more substantial?

Comment: @MoziburUllah Such an examination shouldn't take you too long, as atheism has no suppositions or presuppositions. It's merely a label we've come to use for people who are unconvinced that deities exist. ;)

Comment: Before we worship a God or Jesus we must judge him good, so our moral is not derived and is independent from a God or Jesus. Over time we read the Bible selectively and often metaphorically, and it is the point: we consult our standards of morality in order to judge which aspects of God's word to take literally and which aspects to ignore. Do you really mean to tell me the only reason you try to be good is to gain God's approval and reward, or to avoid his disapproval and punishment? You can not admire a virtue, which is based on fear. Pity those who need God to be good.

Comment: @DeBeaudrap: It's along the right lines. I do note that some religously inspired figures like Al-Hallaj affirmed religion but were able disregard scripture, traditional morality and affirm that God was them.

Comment: I was ambivalent about this, but just to articulate my sense of what the down and closevotes might be about: questions with this degree of weight/urgency would seem to demand an accordingly critical context/motivation -- in other words, a slow/intensive or careful reading. I'm not sure the media can support the breadth of the concern here; it might be more constructive to focus on aspects or moments of the problem you're encountering here that can be encapsulated/given adequate context in the Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consolations of the atheist, according to Christian friends of mine, are self-importance (hubris) and freedom (from ultimate responsibility, from feeling the weight of sin).  I had a rather lengthy conversation (about ten years ago) with a Protestant and a Catholic apologist and they both seemed to make this point, though the Protestant was much more forceful.  I'm not sure whether this was personality or theology.

To expand a little bit more: to admit that God exists is (they claimed) to admit that one should hold oneself inferior to Him; one's own self-worth, importance, glory, etc., is so utterly insignificant compared to His that atheists can be driven by their own vanity to declare that he must not exist.

They also viewed atheism as the ultimate escape-from-responsibility move: since everyone sins, and any sin at all is punishable by death, the only way to escape the conclusion that one deserves death (aside from receiving Jesus' forgiveness) is to deny that God is there at all.  But because God is the source of all morality (direct quote from someone else: "Why don't I steal or murder or all the rest--it's not because I love people so much, it's because God says it's wrong.") once you do away with him you never really need to feel or be responsible for anything--you can do whatever you can get away with and pretend to yourself that it's okay.

These points are not universal consolations, as they are couched strongly in Christian theology, but I was impressed that they were agreed upon by Catholic and Protestant.  (Fair warning, though: sample size was one each, and they were friends, so they may not have even been independent samples (though they did receive different training in apologetics).)  Also, they seem to be plausible *prima facie*, and I have had some atheist friends essentially confirm at least the second (i.e. what they say is logically equivalent to "I like X and the Bible says it's wrong, so I can't believe in God").

Comment: What a fantastically weak answer! Your reasoning goes like this. "I talked to two people, that are not atheists but theists (i.e. can be expected to be biased against atheists). They made some bare claims. I think those clams resonated well with me. So therefore I think those claims are true and present them as the answer".

Comment: @MichaelK - I agree it's weak, but my methodology is explained clearly, and the question postulates that you _have_ to answer it from a religious perspective.  If you have a better source of information, please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Atheism, read in a particular way, has no consolations at all.  That's nothing to say of the sort of atheism that people like Dawkins and Hitchens defend, where one posits a (perhaps Hegelian?) view of free and rational humans progressing towards an end paradise of scientifically informed harmony - you can completely see why that might be consoling to some people.

On Jean-Paul Sartre's conception, Atheism is nothing more or less than the recognition that God does not exist.  God, here, is not to be understood through the lens of any particular faith or belief system, or of a personal psychological representation or theory acquired through language, social graces or instinctive defense mechanism.  God, in Sartre's view, is the possibility of direction external to the unframed plane of our existence.  Atheism is to be read as the understanding that **Nature and Cosmology do not care about you**, and that its principles and functioning are not going to be simply presented to you to follow for some positive end.

Consolation isn't found in Atheism as such.  Existentialism qua Sartre is a view of human existence as theorising about what we and others do and must do to live on in spite of the truth of Atheism.  This creates a space for a certain amount of "authentic" faith, that recognises the instrumental nature of the mythologies and principles of our social realities, opening up new spaces for similar constructions and organization, and yet chooses to participate in them despite their constructed or mythological nature as a way of surviving in an ambivalent reality.  We're finding this a lot in ideas in post-structural Christianity, and there is an interesting argument to be made to the effect that Atheism does not necessarily conflict with the idea of religious belief, even where we recognise that it does crucially oppose both the moral normativity and the metaphysical claims of pretty much every religion or cult that currently exists.